# How to importrange dynamically based on dropdown/variable

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to dynamically retrieve all rows where a status = [Dynamically chosen value] from a drop down list.

## below you can see my current formula:

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("https://example.com", "Tracker!A1:V"), "select * where Col7 = 'B1' ")
```

[image]

Here is an example where you can see what I'm trying to do (Status is A1, and A2 is the formula grabbing all rows from another sheet)
[image]

If I select the "A1" in the formula is brings up "In Progress" so it appears to be referencing the correct value, but it doesnt work unless I explicitly write the status into the formula as a text object..

As noted below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use cell references, you have to escape them using `'"&cell&"'`

`QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("your_url","your_sheet!your_range"),"Select * where Col7 = '"&A1&"'",0))`